# Does the jQuery.clone method have side effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

If $dom is a jQuery element,

Can this line be removed safely if `a` is not used after?

```
var a = $dom.clone(true,true);
```

As the method clone the dom, I think `$dom.clone(false,false)` do not have [side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect). If think that method cannot thrown an error too. I'm more sceptical about the clone of events. I think if the cloned element is not reattached, it doesn't have effects, but I'm not sure. Is there any event that can be propagated to detached dom event? (if yes, then I'm not sure we can removed safely that line)

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

The aim of the question is to determine if the absence of `@nosideeffects` is a bug in the externs definition of `.clone()` here : https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js#L405

Comment: "Can this line be removed safely if a is not used after?" if you don't use a there is no point in cloning it.

Comment: @Liam: "side effects" is a fairly common term in software engineering theory. `console.log` has side-effects, for instance; it's not a pure function (it has output).

Comment: @Liam I mean side effects according to the closure compiler behaviour, which, I think, can be explained by: "Can this line be removed safely if a is not used after?" (independently of the code around it)

Comment: @Liam of course, there is no point. But we are in a specific context : closure compiler. It minify/rewrite the code. In some situation to compiler can determine that "a" is not used after. If the compiler arrived at that conclusion, can it remove the clone too, or will that change the code behaviour?

Comment: no event from the dom can propagate to an element outside the dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the absense of that annotation is a bug in terms of the Closure Compiler's definition of "no side effects" is pretty much up to Google. :-)

In at least jQuery 1.x, calling `.clone` with `true, true` mutates jQuery's state information, information it **doesn't** just hold on the elements returned and associated with the jQuery object that ends up referenced by `a`: jQuery's data cache for the element (which is used both for "data" and for event handler information) is not stored on the element itself, it's stored in a structure within jQuery that's *keyed* by an expando property on the element. So it's not a truly pure function; it mutates the state of something: jQuery's data cache.

In jQuery 2.x and above, I believe the information is stored on the element itself (since 2.x and above don't support IE6 and IE7, which couldn't do GC across the DOM/JS boundary correctly).

Comment: So it's not a bug for this file. Now I'm still unsure for jQuery 2.x and 3.x. The original discussion start there : https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/1839#discussion_r70758049 (need to press F5 after page load if you want github to scroll to the right place...)